# Drag and Drop from listbox to textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I have a very simple question i think but i seemed to have complicated the idea, perhaps someone can guide me or help me out a bit.

I have a listbox and textbox, i want to copy text from the list box to the textbox.

My code in WPF is as follows:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="465" Width="681">
<Grid>
    <ListBox x:Name="listbox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="405" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="208" MouseDown="listbox1_MouseDown">
        <ListBoxItem Content="Gordon"/>
        <ListBoxItem Content="Nico"/>
    </ListBox>
    <TextBox x:Name="textbox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="405" Margin="289,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="364" SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True" Cursor="IBeam" AcceptsReturn="True" AllowDrop="True" DragEnter="textbox1_DragEnter"/>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

My code in C# is as follow and this is where I'm stuck:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void listbox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        DragDrop.DoDragDrop(listbox1, listbox1.SelectedItem.ToString(), DragDropEffects.Copy);
    }

    private void textbox1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    }

    private void textbox1_PreviewDragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }

}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And you're stuck because?

Comment: the DoDragDrop doesnt seem to be supported by WPF

Comment: Try https://code.google.com/p/gong-wpf-dragdrop/ _The GongSolutions.Wpf.DragDrop library is a drag'n'drop framework for WPF._

Comment: @AhmedKRAIEM Thank you for your reply, the issue is that all the examples i find are listbox to listbox and not to a texbox, i cannot find anything to textbox. It seems as copying to different controls is slightly different

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use:

```
DragDrop.DoDragDrop( listbox1,
                         lsitbox1.SelectedItem.ToString(),
                         DragDropEffects.Copy);
```

Handle `DragEnter` event for the `Textbox` control as per [MSDN `DragEnter` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.dragenter%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Handle `Drop` event for the `Textbox` control as per [MSDN `Drop` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.drop%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

You can also additionally handle the `DragOver` event for the `Textbox` control for more customized Drag drop handling and processing.

You can find more on Drag and Drop process in WPF in [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742859%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) MSDN article.

Comment: I have made amends to your recommendations in the question above, i am working on the rest now

Answer (score 0):

Here is my c# answer to my Question, its working i just have one issue.

The issue is that a list box item has to be selected in order to drag it, how do i select and drag the item at the same time on a mousedown event without having to click it first?

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void listbox1_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (listbox1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            ListBoxItem mySelectedItem = listbox1.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem;
            if (mySelectedItem != null)
            {
                DragDrop.DoDragDrop(listbox1, mySelectedItem.Content.ToString(), DragDropEffects.Copy);
            }

        }
    }

    private void textbox1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    }

    private void textbox1_PreviewDragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void textbox1_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        string tstring;
        tstring = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.StringFormat).ToString();
        textbox1.Text += " " + tstring;
    }

    private void textbox1_PreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

    }


}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

```
private void listbox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
                DragDrop.DoDragDrop(listbox1, listbox1.SelectedItem.ToString(), DragDropEffects.All);
        }
```